# Are Skittles Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

Skittles are a fruit-flavored candy that has been seen with hechshers in various areas. My question is, are Skittles kosher even if they do not hold a hechsher on the package? They are gelatin free.

For instance, in the Dallas area, you can find Skittles with a hechsher. Where I live, there is no hechsher on the bag.

Comment: I believe those which are imported from Israel have a Hechsher. I could be wrong

Comment: Why would you think they don't need a hechsher?

Comment: @DonielF - Sometimes packages only have a  _printed_ hechsher if there is a Rabbinical authority in the area in which they are being produced. There is no Rabbinical authority where I live, thus some items that are kosher do not have a hechsher printed on the package but are authorized kosher. For example, some canned drinks here are like that.

Comment: @ezra So first of all, just because all of the ingredients are kosher that doesn't make the item kosher. Things heated beyond yad soledes bo that touch an object that within the last 24 hours touched treif food that at the time was also beyond yad soledes bo will be treif. A mashgiach is in charge of preventing such a scenario, among other things. Second, why Skittles? Are you going to go ask about apple juice and Jolly Ranchers and anything else in your grocery that lacks a hechsher? CYLOR is at the top of all pages for a reason.

Comment: @DonielF Maybe he was wondering if anyone had seen it on a kosher list. It can be hard to search them one by one.

Comment: @SAH How does that address my questions?

Comment: @DonielF While your essential point is true, its converse is true too: just because there is no hechsher does not mean the item is *not* kosher.

Comment: @Oliver You totally missed my point. I suggested asking when an item needs a hechsher and when it doesn’t - that would address both what I said and what you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A search of the Internet showed:

1) [from OU](https://oukosher.org/kosher-alerts/skittles/)
February 26, 2009
Brands: 
Products: Skittles Candy Fan UPC# 6 09454 61492 6 Skittles Dry Erase Message Board UPC# 6 09454 61501 5 
Company: Candyrific- Louisville, KY 
Issue:
An unauthorized OU-D symbol was inadvertently placed on these products’ labels. These products are not certified Kosher by the Orthodox Union. Consumers spotting this product are requested to contact the Orthodox Union at 212-613-8241 or via email at kashalerts@ou.org.

2) [KLBD (London) noshguide Summer 2016](http://noshguide.theus.org.uk/#p=1)  says that Skittles are not kosher. A kosher version is avaialable from some kosher stores.

Comment: More info, perhaps: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42996